# Very basic python

Tags: python, dice

Getting an error but I don't know why..(I'm learning)
My code;

```
import random
input("Hit enter to roll the dice")
global answer
def rollDice():
    result = random.randrange(1,6)
    print ("It landed on.." + str(result))
    answer = input("would you like to play again? [y/n]")
rollDice();


if (answer == "y" or "Y"):
    rollDice();
```

Error; (some of the script works)

```
Hit enter to roll the dice
It landed on..5
would you like to play again? [y/n]y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "diceRoller.py", line 11, in <module>
    while (answer == "y" or "Y"):
NameError: name 'answer' is not defined
```

Comment: [Short Description of Python Scoping Rules](http://stackoverflow.com/q/291978/2359271)

Comment: `global answer` belongs *inside* the function. You'll have another problem after that, see [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On top of what the answers are saying, I would advise you not to use `global`, instead I would `return` whether the person wanted to continue or not, and continue based off that, for example:

```
import random
input("Hit enter to roll the dice")
def rollDice():
    result = random.randrange(1,6)
    print("It landed on.. " + str(result))
    answer = input("Would you like to play again? [y/n]")
    if answer in ("y", "Y"):
        return True
    return False

while rollDice():
    continue
```

Also, use a loop instead of an `if` statement. Otherwise you won't be able to ask the user if he/she wants to continue indefinitely.

Comment: That is alot tidier.. thanks! however whats the purpose of returning false if we're returning true if they say Y for yes?

Comment: Once you get to a return statement, you break out of the function. So if the user inputs "y" or "Y", you leave the function. The `return False` is to handle the other case, when they don't input "y" or "Y".

Comment: Or just `return (answer in ("y", "Y"))`

Answer (score 0):

Your function definition is the thing that needs to know that `answer` is global. So put your `global` declaration inside the definition body.

```
def rollDice():
    global answer
    result = random.randrange(1,6)
    print ("It landed on.." + str(result))
    answer = input("would you like to play again? [y/n]")
```

Also

```
if (answer == "y" or "Y"):
```

should be

```
if answer in ('y', 'Y'):
```

otherwise you are checking if either `(answer=="y")` or `("Y")`, the latter of which always evaluates to `True`.

If you want to keep rolling indefinitely as long as the users answers affirmatively, then your `if` should be a `while`.

```
while answer in ('y', 'Y'):
```

Comment: made the changes that you said, however it will only loop 3 times before stopping, why?

Comment: @DamhanRichardson I can't see any reason it would stop after 3 iterations. It doesn't do that when I try it.

Answer (score 0):

the `global` keyword has to be inside the function body. Also, like Falmarri said, `if (answer=="y" or "Y")` needs to be `if answer=="y" or answer=="Y"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `global answer` has no effect in the global scope. Put it inside the function.

But it's pretty difficult to debug your code as the traceback is referring to a line of code that does not appear in the source you show! (`while` vs `if`)

In any case, `if answer = 'y' or 'Y'` should be `if answer in tuple('yY')`

Comment: this will make 'yY' also to mean True. I don't think that was desired here

Comment: @user3885927 Good catch! `if answer in tuple('yY')` in that case.